# How to Test Against a Form's "input.placeholder" Attribute for JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, placeholder, nodelist

I have a script wherein I would like to get the form's placeholder attribute and then use as a conditional in a function like so (this doesn't seem right to me, so I'm not surprised it doesn't work):

```
if (document.getElementsByName("Name").input.placeholder == "Enter Name") {
    //do something
}
```

The wrapper function actually takes the form as argument:

```
function form_function(form) {
    var input = document.getElementsByName("Name");
    var placeholder = input.placeholder;

    if (placeholder == "Empty") {
        // do something
    }
}
```

I've tried a few different things to no avail. The error console is telling me that the input is undefined. For example, I started with:

`var placeholder = form.input.placeholder;`

and that didn't work either.

I then ran some alert tests and when I just alert the input I get `NodeList` object, which I'm not sure how to deal with.

So I tried looping through the `NodeList` and got some objects I'm unsure how to use.

```
var inputList = document.getElementsByName("Name");

var inputArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
    inputArray[i] = inputList[i];
    alert(inputArray[i]);
}
```

Alert gives `[object HTMLInputElement]`

Basically, I just want to test against the placeholder value in the form with the specific name attribute. Seems I've gone awry...

Thanks.

Comment: `getElementsByName` returns a `NodeList`: if you look closely, "Elements" is plural. You want `document.getElementsByName("Name")[n]` to get the `n`th element with the name `Name`, and you can use `document.getElementsByName("Name")[n].placeholder` to get its placeholder value.

Comment: Yes, I just realized this as I wrapped up the question. In my case, there is but one object in the list, so I used `document.getElementsByName("Name")[0].placeholder` but it still not working as I expected... I will update my question with results. Thanks for the heads up, nonetheless!

Comment: @apsillers - are you going to offer an answer? I'd accept it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @apsillers correctly stated, the elements re turned are in an array so I needed to capture the one I needed. I went with this:

`placeholder = document.getElementsByName("Name")[0].placeholder;`

and then was able to use this in the function as required.